# Growing Oyster mushroom: Is my spawn growing healthily?

Tags: mushrooms

I am trying to grow oyster mushrooms. They had a very strong smell which dissipated slowly over the week now ( I actually asked another question here  [Question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/48862/very-heavy-smell-while-growing-oyster-mushrooms) ) I am not sure of how the process is going as I don't know anything about oyster mushrooms in particular and it is my first time. So can you confirm that my spawn is growing healthy with the provided picture(s)?

What I did:

I used a 3-4 gallon transparent bucket which I drilled holes into.

I used woodchips and oat bran as substrate.

I added the spawn I bought online in layers.

Stored them in a dark place

Here are the photo of spawn after 8-9ish days

[image: Spawn]

[image: Spawn]

[image: Spawn]

I can provide any information that you request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks normal, the only thing to watch for is the horrible green mould contamination (that's why I stopped growing).
Later there may be drops appearing looking like honey - not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. No visible mold for now. When will I start spraying water? Is it after the mycelium completely wraps the bucket or should I start now?

Comment: Later? I dont know for sure, but feel that while there is still condensation inside the mycelium isnt drying out. Unlike with plants, the water isnt transpired. The instructions I read also said to keep in the dark until time to start fruiting.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you don't need to spray to encourage fruiting. Most of the time I don't spray unless the room is very dry even after they start fruiting. But once the entire container is colonized, you might find you need to drop the temperature by 10-15 deg. F to trigger fruiting. But most oysters are such aggressive growers/fruiters you don't even need to do that.